# DataGrid In devextreme ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: .net-core, datagrid, asp.net-core-mvc, devexpress, devextreme

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project with devextreme and I added a datagrid.

I want to modify this column in datagrid to be list of button, in selectBox I want items in it to be Button not pure text.

How I can do this ?

- .net
- Devextreme

Code:

```
columns.Add().Caption(@L["Actions"].Value).CellTemplate(@<text>
                @(Html.DevExtreme().SelectBox()
                .OnSelectionChanged("DoAction")
                .DataSource(ActionsName)
                .ValueExpr("id")
                .DisplayExpr("text")
                .Value(0))
                </text>
        );
```